# Classifier Random Forest Accuracy Not Consistent

Tags: random, machine-learning

I tried running a random forest classifier over different training sample sizes. The results are very strange because I could not replicate my accuracy with the same sample size in the second iteration although nothing else changed. Moreover the accuracy does not improve with larger sample sizes.

My results:

```
TSS Method  Accuracy(1st Iteration) Accuracy(2nd Iteration)
5   RF      0,514       
20  RF      0,510       
50  RF      0,524       
100 RF      0,541                   0,507   
110 RF      0,496
200 RF      0,506       
300 RF      0,502       
400 RF      0,445
```

Is the implementation of the classifier or method wrong or are these results ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the implementation of the classifier or method wrong or are these
>   results ok?

We cannot conclude from the posted table of classification accuracy results that "the classifier or method is wrong". I can come up with at least several explanations. (*And it would be nice if data is provided.*)

The simplest explanation is that none of your variables is decisive for the class labels in your data. Below is an example.

### Example of no accuracy change

Consider the following steps:

1. Take the Titanic data.
2. Remove the variables "passenger class" and "passenger sex".
3. Build and a measure the accuracy of classifiers with training data samples with different sizes.

Here is the code for these steps:

```
testSetName = "Titanic";

trainingSet = 
  ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", testSetName}, "TrainingData"];
 testSet = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", testSetName}, "TestData"];

trainingSet2 = trainingSet;
trainingSet2[[All, 1]] = trainingSet2[[All, 1]][[All, {2}]];
testSet2 = testSet;
testSet2[[All, 1]] = testSet2[[All, 1]][[All, {2}]];

clRes = Table[(
    clFunc2 = 
     Classify[RandomSample[trainingSet2, n], 
      Method -> "RandomForest"]; 
    cm2 = ClassifierMeasurements[clFunc2, testSet2]; {n, 
     cm2["Accuracy"]}), {n, {5, 20, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400}}];
TableForm[clRes, TableHeadings -> {None, {"Sample size", "Accuracy"}}]
```

[image]

We can explain the classification results by looking at the histograms of the age distributions wishing the class labels:

```
asPairs = 
  DeleteCases[
   Map[Flatten@Apply[List, #] &, trainingSet2], {___, _Missing, ___}];

Histogram[#[[All, 1]], 20, "Probability"] & /@ GroupBy[asPairs, Last]
```

[image]

We can see that the histograms are too much alike, hence "passenger age" is not a decisive variable.

### Importance of variables investigation

If we apply the procedure described in [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102801/34008) of ["How can I determine the importance of variables from Classify?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102762/how-can-i-determine-the-importance-of-variables-from-classify) we can see that
"passenger age" has no decisiveness on the classification (and "passenger sex" is quite decisive):

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thank for the reply. I am trying to classify pictures of tables and chairs and wanted to compare sample sizes and different classifier methods. So there are no variables like in the titanic data set.

Comment: @user3483676 I have worked on classifiers with/for images, and I have seen classifiers with *overall* accuracies like the ones you show (close to 0.5). But for the most important class labels I was able to make the classifiers to achieve 0.7-0.8 precision and and 0.6-0.8 recall (while the overall accuracy is still being ~0.5).

Comment: How important is preprocessing of pictures? If you use ConformImages don't you lose a lot of information in the picture? It is faster of course and you run out of memory otherwise.

Comment: @user3483676 Yeah processing is important, I would say half the battle. You might also consider using image data like luminosity, levels, etc. which are found before using `ConformImages`.