# Revealing correlation between one parameter and set of parameters.

Tags: cluster-analysis, correlation

Probably it is duplicate (but I could not fine it) or it is a question for MathOverflow.
Still I would like to use Mathematica to analyze my data.
In experiment I measure the parameter "P" of the set of objects. This is extremely difficult and pricy. From the other hand I can easily measure the set of parameters "p1,p2,...,p10" of all objects. I know that they somehow correlates with parameter "P", but I do not know how. Is it possible reveal this hidden correlation? Should I use some modification of PrincipalComponents or cluster analysis?

Comment: This may be a question for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), the companion site for probability and statistics. Once you have a method in mind, then we can see how to implement that in MMA.

Answer (score 5):

If you can build a classifier for your data, e.g.

$$F : \{p^k_1,p^k_2,...,p^k_{10}\} \longrightarrow P_i ,$$

then you can use the approach described in this discussion:

["How can I determine the importance of variables from Classify?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102762/how-can-i-determine-the-importance-of-variables-from-classify).

> Should I use some modification of PrincipalComponents or cluster
>   analysis?

The document [Importance of variables investigation guide"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/Documentation/Importance-of-variables-investigation-guide.pdf), has much more extensive descriptions, explanations, and code for importance of variables investigation using classifiers, Mosaic plots, Decision trees, Association rules, and ***Dimension reduction***.

If all of your data is numerical you can compare simple variable-to-variable scatter plots as shown in this image for the Fisher Iris Dataset:

[image]