# LinearModelFit to Indicate Influence on outcome

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I want to determine the influence of factors on the outcome of a situation using `LinearModelFit`. I've tried to figure out how to do it by looking at online examples but I'm getting nowhere.

For example, taking the following data (these are completely made up values):

[image: Plantdata]

So I want to calculate the influence the four factors (time, rain, humidity, no. plants) have on the overall flower growth (row 6).

I know how to import the data and put it into table form but after that I get lost.

Can someone show me how I would make this into a `LinearModelFit` and finally a `ParameterTable` which shows me the influence of each factor.

Out of curiousity, are there other ways of indicating the impact of factors?

---

Edit:

I have tried to implement the classifier method, I believe I have got the first phase of the classifier training method but I'm not sure where to go from here since I'm using my own data set and not ExampleData.

flowertab = SemanticImport["https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/flowername1/flower1.xlsx"]

[image: flower3]

`flowerflow = Normal@flowertab[All, Sequence[Most@# -> Last@#] &]`

[image: flower4]

How to I apply my data to the titanic method:

```
testSetName = "Titanic"; 
trainingSet = 
  ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", testSetName}, "TrainingData"];
 testSet = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", testSetName}, "TestData"];
varNames = 
  Flatten[List @@ 
    ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", testSetName}, 
     "VariableDescriptions"]];

mres = Association@Map[
    Function[{clMethod},
     cf = Classify[trainingSet, Method -> clMethod];
     accRes = 
      AccuracyByVariableShuffling[cf, testSet, varNames, 
       "FScoreLabels" -> "survived"];
     clMethod -> (accRes[None] - Rest[accRes])/accRes[None]
     ], {"LogisticRegression", "NearestNeighbors", "NeuralNetwork", 
     "RandomForest", "SupportVectorMachine"}] ;

Dataset[mres]
```

to finally get

```
mres = Association@Map[
    Function[{clMethod},
     cf = Classify[trainingSet, Method -> clMethod];
     accRes = 
      AccuracyByVariableShuffling[cf, testSet, varNames, 
       "FScoreLabels" -> "survived"];
     clMethod -> (accRes[None] - Rest[accRes])/accRes[None]
     ], {"LogisticRegression", "NearestNeighbors", "NeuralNetwork", 
     "RandomForest", "SupportVectorMachine"}] ;

Dataset[mres]
```

[image: titanic3]

Comment: One way is to use `Classify` and [this guide](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/MarkdownDocuments/Importance-of-variables-investigation-guide.md) for variables importance investigation. Also, see the related discussion ["How can I determine the importance of variables from Classify?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102762/34008).

Comment: If by "influence" you mean a measure for each data point as to their level of "influence", look at the `LinearModelFit` documentation for `"CookDistances"`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I've spent the evening reading those articles and attempting that method, they're very very helpful thank you! However I'm having trouble applying it to my data and have edited my question, could you help? (Sorry it's quite long winded)

Comment: @hellohi Please post your data!

Comment: @AntonAntonov apologies, I've posted it under the edit

Comment: @hellohi The data you posted is too small for the procedure I suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {{13.5, 2, 90, 20, 10}, {6, 1, 80, 4, 7}, {10, 3.5, 85, 8, 
   8}, {15, 9, 70, 10, 8}, {14, 4, 60, 11, 9}, {3, 0, 60, 4, 2}, {8, 
   1, 64, 15, 1}};
lmf = LinearModelFit[data, {1, a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}];
lmf["ANOVATable"]
```

This is the simple linear model fit in each of the input parameters (rows 2-5), listed as variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` respectively, and the ANOVA table describing their effects. This is the simple linear model assuming that the effects of each input are completely independent and the presence of a constant term, see the documentation of `LinearModelFit` for alternatives.

Also see `lmf["Properties"]` from this example for other information available automatically from *Mathematica*'s `LinearModelFit`.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Just to double check, this model fit is indeed measuring the effects they have on the results in the 6th row? :)

Comment: @hellohi Yes, this model is fitting the 4 parameters to the last element of each entry in the `data` table.

Comment: @eyeorble Sorry may I ask another question? I'm a little confused about the p-values of the parameter table and I'm finding conflicting information. If the p-value is, say, 0.9 I can assume this has a higher influence on the selected row than a factor with a p-value of 0.01?

Comment: @hellohi Generally p-values are the probability that a variable is _insignificant_, so a p-value of 0.9 generally means that the variable has little to no influence on the resulting model, while 0.01 generally means that it has a relatively significant influence.

Comment: Just a verification on the LinearModelFit syntax, because I am working on a predictive regression: if I have e.g. 2 independent and 1 dependent variable, the dependent variable goes in the third column (position) while the independent in the first and second column (position), with the function looking like LinearModelFit[{x, y, z}, {x, y}, {x,y}] . Is that correct?

Comment: @Titus Yes, that should work. The documentation has some examples for that use case (under the Scope heading). However, if you have more specific questions about `LinearModelFit`, please consider asking a separate question here. In general the dependent variable is in the last position.